# Django Rest Framework - Uploading an Image with Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to submit a form with Ajax to a Django rest-framework (3.0) ViewSet.

I can submit just fine using a curl request but my Ajax request gives me the following response:

> The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.

Here is my django-rest code:

```
class UserEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
""" Used locally to allow users to edit their user profile"""


class Meta:
    model = User
    include = ["about", "avatar"]

class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (AllowReadonlyOrAdminOrSelf,)

parser_classes = (parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FormParser)
lookup_field = 'uuid'

def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.all()

def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Use different serializers depending on the request"""
    uuid = self.kwargs.get("uuid", None)
    request = self.request.method;

    if request == "POST" and uuid:
        return UserEditSerializer
    return AuthorSerializer

def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = UserEditSerializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And my AJAX:

```
        $("#profile_update_form").submit(function(e) {
        var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : '{% url 'api:User-detail' user.uuid  %}',
            type : "POST",
            data : data,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success : ajaxSuccessLog,
            contentType : false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            error : ajaxErrorLog
        });
    });
```

I've also tried using the [JQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to submit. After debugging the problem definitely occurs here:

```
serializer = UserEditSerializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
```

Right when the data gets passed into the serializer. I am able to submit the form properly if I don't include an image field.

**EDIT**

As requested here is my django form code:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""Form for editing user profile"""

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['about', 'avatar']
```

And my form template:

```
<form id="profile_update_form" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        {{ author_form.as_p }}
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you should use `request.DATA` not `request.data`. Also, you can check for uploaded files using `request.FILE`. Check it.

Comment: Actually in rest-framework 3.0 request .data contains request.DATA and request.FILE. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#.data

Comment: Could you also post your form code ? I believe that's where your problem is coming from.